# ПРОЦЕНТ чи ВІДСОТОК?

Tags: вживання-слів

Яке слово правильно вживати - ПРОЦЕНТ чи ВІДСОТОК? Чи обидва?

Comment: Не певен чому вам поставили -1, та підозрюю, що через те, що відповідь дуже легко гуглиться. І не зрозуміло чим вам не підійшли результати з пошуку.

Comment: Все можна загуглити :) Але ж мета цього проекту - збирати актуальні знання у зручному форматі

Answer (score 5):

Це, технічно, одне й те ж саме слово. Просто **процент** має іншомовне походження (від лат. *per centum* — сотня).

> [Уроки державної мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53407/25993.html) (з газети «Хрещатик»)
>
> **ПРОЦЕНТ , ВІДСОТОК**
> Чи є різниця в значенні слів відсоток і процент?
> Ні, немає. Вони передають той самий зміст. Процент з італійської через німецьку перейшов у східнослов'янські мови, а відсоток – калькований вислів з латинізованого терміна, що буквально означає “за сто”, “наріст від ста”, звідси й “від соток”. Обома лексемами активно послуговувались у Західній Україні в минулому сторіччі. За радянських часів відсоток вважали мало не “націоналістичним словом” і нещадно вилучали з текстів, а сьогодні майже не вживають процент, хоча це також крайність. Бо він нормальний синонім. І як термін вельми потрібний науково-технічній сфері.

Comment: Щодо останнього, невже слово має бути іншомовного походження щоби увійти у науково-технічну галузь?

Answer (score 3):

Словники (наприклад, [«Словник української мови» в 11 томах](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html), [«Словники України online» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)) **містять обидва слова**, без жодних позначок щодо обмежень вживання (мовляв, діалектне, застаріле, розмовне абощо).

Я чув, що деякі мовознавці, коли ми маємо синоніми, один з яких запозичений, а інший — українського походження, радять використовувати варіант українського походження. Але це не є якимось жорстким правилом, лише питанням уподобань.

[Частота трапляння](http://batchman.parasolcorpus.org/NGyears.html) цих слів у [«Генеральному регіонально анотованому корпусі української мови»](http://uacorpus.org/) версії 10:

> [image: частоти]

Comment: Дуже цікавий графік! Тобто на сьогодні "відсоток" очевидно набагато більш вживаний варіант

Comment: @Oleg, причому (може це, звісно, збіг, але виглядає, що) здебільшого в історії домінував _процент_ (і в часи царської Росії / Австро-Угорщини, і в часи СРСР), а _відсоток_ виходив у лідери двічі: в часи [Розстріляного відродження](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Розстріляне_відродження) і в часи незалежності.

Answer (score 2):

Математична позначка **«%»** може називатися **«ПРОЦЕНТ»** або **«ВІДСОТОК»**. [Wiki](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA)

**Особливості вжитку термінів «ПРОЦЕНТ» і «ВІДСОТОК» у фінансовій сфері:**

1. Процент // [Банківська енциклопедія](https://old.bank.gov.ua/doccatalog/document?id=112997) (стор.356, С.Г. Арбузов, Ю.В. Колобов, В.І. Міщенко).

> **ПРОЦЕНТ**
> **(Interest) – дохід, який сплачується** (нараховується) позичальником на користь кредитора **у вигляді плати за використання** залучених на
> визначений строк **коштів або майна**. До *П.* включають: платіж за
> використання коштів або товарів (робіт, послуг), отриманих у кредит;
> платіж за використання коштів, залучених у депозит; платіж за
> придбання товарів у розстрочку.
>
> Проценти нараховуються у вигляді відсотків на основну суму
> заборгованості або фіксованих сум. У разі коли залучення коштів
> здійснюється шляхом продажу облігацій, казначейських зобов’язань або
> ощадних (депозитних) сертифікатів, емітованих позичальником, сума П.
> визначається шляхом нарахування відсотків на номінал такого цінного
> паперу, виплати фіксованої премії чи виграшу або шляхом визначення
> різниці між ціною розміщення та ціною погашення такого цінного паперу
> (сума дисконту). Платежі за іншими цивільно-правовими договорами,
> незалежно від того, чи встановлені вони в абсолютних (фіксованих)
> цінах або у відсотках до суми договору або до іншої вартісної бази, не
> вважають П.

2. Процент // [СЛОВНИК фінансово-правових термінів](http://ndi-fp.nusta.com.ua/files/doc/slovnyk-finpravo.pdf)
   (стор. 415-416, за ред. Л.К.Воронової).

> **Процент – це:** 1) сота частка числа, прийнятого за ціле, за одиницю; 2)
> **дохід**, одержуваний за кожні 100 грошових одиниць, вкладених у банк; 3)
> **плата**, одержувана кредитором від боржника за користування відданими в
> позику грішми; 4) **винагорода**, обчислювана залежно від обороту, доходу.
>
> **Процент – плата позичальника у боргових (кредитних) відносинах**.
> Розрізняють такі його форми: депозитний, позиковий, обліковий.
> *Процент депозитний* – плата банків за кошти, що зберігаються на
> депозитних (вкладних) рахунках клієнтів. *Процент позиковий* – одна з
> центральних категорій ринкової економіки, що є формою ціни позичених
> коштів (капіталу). Він являє собою винагороду, яку заощадження
> приносять тому, хто дає гроші в борг, а також ціну, яку сплачує
> позичальник кредитору. Кількісно позиковий процент може бути
> визначений нормою або ставкою. Норма процента обчислюється відношенням
> доходу кредитора від наданого кредиту до абсолютної величини цього
> кредиту. Розмір процентної ставки визначає співвідношення попиту і
> пропозиції кредитних ресурсів. Крім того, на величину процента
> впливають такі чинники, як політика центрального емісійного банку,
> циклічні та сезонні коливання кон’юнктури, темпи інфляції, зміна
> валютного курсу, стан платіжного балансу та інші. *Процент обліковий* –
> це: 1) плата, що знімається банками за авансування грошей шляхом
> купівлі (обліку) векселів, цінних паперів, купонів, облігацій та інших
> боргових зобов’язань до настання термінів оплати за ними. Дорівнює
> різниці між номіналом боргового зобов’язання та сумою, сплачуваною
> банком у разі дострокового викупу, цього зобов’язання;  2) позиковий,
> кредитний процент, стягуваний банками за надання міжбанківського
> кредиту.

3. УКРАЇНОМОВНА СУТНІСТЬ ВИЗНАЧЕНОСТІ СЛІВ-ТЕРМІНІВ «ПРОЦЕНТ» ТА «ВІДСОТОК», [Наукова стаття, 2019](https://essuir.sumdu.edu.ua/bitstream-download/123456789/76710/1/Zaitsev_Sydorenko_Avtorske%20svidotstvo_%E2%84%96_94509.PDF) (Зайцев О.В., Сидоренко О.П.).

> Отже, **у фінансах** слово-термін **«процент» – це сума грошей, що виступає формою плати, яку сплачує позичальник кредитору за користування
> позиченими коштами**.
>
> Неможливо до золотих монет (гульденів) докладати **«%»**, докладати
> можливо лише гроші, а вони в такому контексті фрази мають назву
> **«проценти», а не «відсотки»**.

Таким чином, терміни **«процент» і «відсоток»** в загальному вжитку рівнозначні, але в банківській справі та кредитно-фінансовій сфері, якщо йдеться про суму грошей до сплати за використання позичених коштів або майна (в натуральному вимірі), треба вживати термін **«Процент»**. Фінансові уствнови зазвичай надають визначення цього терміну в Договорі.

Фінансовий **«ПРОЦЕНТ»** – це сума грошей, що вимірюється у валютних одиницях і може позначатися як **UAH**, **$** та ін. Фінансовий **«ПРОЦЕНТ»** не може бути позначений знаком **«%»**.

Comment: А можете, будь ласка, коротко викласти суть наведеного там? ([На Stack Exchange не прийнято робити відповіді лише з посилань](/help/how-to-answer): «Provide context for links. …Please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline».)

Comment: @Yola, як я розумію: слово _процент_ де-факто вживають не лише в прямому (математичному) значенні, а і як скорчення до «процентна плата», «величина процентної плати» (англ. _interest_); і в 3-му джерелі Зайцев і Сидоренко пропонують використовувати слово _процент_ ЛИШЕ в цьому значенні. Звісно, добре було б, якби сам автор відповіді розписав, як він розуміє подане в 3-му джерелі (при цьому додавши, що це пропозиція конкретних осіб, але не факт, що загальновизна практика).